# Define custom error messages on invalid attribute call

Tags: python, class, error-handling, attributes

How do I define custom error messages for specific invalid attribute calls in python?

I wrote a class thats attribute assignment is dependent on the input on instance creation and like to return a more descriptive error message if an unassigned attribute is called:

```
class test:
    def __init__(self, input):
        if input == 'foo': 
            self.type = 'foo'
            self.a = 'foo'
        if input == 'bar': 
            self.type = 'bar'
            self.b = 'bar'

class_a = test('foo')

print class_a.a
print class_a.b
```

On execution I get this error-message

```
AttributeError: test instance has no attribute 'b'
```

Instead of that I'd like to get something like

```
AttributeError: test instance is of type 'foo' and therefore has no b-attribute
```

Comment: `input` and `type` are Python reserved words. It is best to avoid using them

Answer (score 1):

Override **getattr** in your class.

```
class test(object):
    def __init__(self, input):
        if input == 'foo': 
            self.type = 'foo'
            self.a = 'foo'
        if input == 'bar': 
            self.type = 'bar'
            self.b = 'bar'

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        raise AttributeError("'test' object is of type '{}' and therefore has no {}-attribute.".format(self.type, attr))
```

**getattr** is called when python can't find the attribute normally.  Essentially, it's like an "except" clause when your class raises an AttributeError.